# Converting string to integer and vice versa in Python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, integer

I have a string for example

```
>>> sample = "Hello World!"
```

What I want to make a function which can convert `sample` to int. I know about `chr()` and `ord()`. I've used this so far:

**For String to Int**

```
>>> res="".join([str(ord(char)) for char in sample])
>>> print(res)
72101108108111328711111410810033
```

Now the problem arise. How can I convert `res` back to `sample`. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

`Note: sample string can also have unicode characters in it`

Edit :

```
nchars=len(sample)
res = sum(ord(sample[byte])<<8*(nchars-byte-1) for byte in range(nchars)) # string to int
print(''.join(chr((res>>8*(nchars-byte-1))&0xFF) for byte in range(nchars))) #int to string
```

I found this solution but this is very slow do someone know to improve this

Comment: This is not possible because of different lengths of numbers (number strings, to be precise) no one can tell which digit belongs to which number.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have found a solution but it is very slow. Can you tell me to better the solution in Edit

Comment: How do you use bit shift operator on string in your solution?

Comment: Combining all the ASCII together making a big string. You know ASCII values have different sizes like `0~255` so how can you sure what character you need? avoid combining all the ASCII together rather use an ASCII list then convert to string. Also  your edited question isn't a valid way to get back

Comment: @SayandipDutta by converting string to byte

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing an `ord` in the `string to int` part? like `ord(sample[byte]) << 8*...`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta You are right I missed it. Do you know how can I fast this line of code as this is very slow for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sample = "Hello World!"
d1={k:str(ord(v)) for k,v in list(enumerate(sample))}
''.join(d1.values())
'72101108108111328711111410810033'
res1="".join([chr(int(char)) for char in d1.values()])
res1
'Hello World!'
```

In order to avoid the problem of `which ord(chr) belongs to which chr?` we need a mapping like data structure and dict is the best to store the each string and assign them to unique key using `enumerate` which will generate the keys on fly.

Our `d1` looks like this:

```
{0: '72',
 1: '101',
 2: '108',
 3: '108',
 4: '111',
 5: '32',
 6: '87',
 7: '111',
 8: '114',
 9: '108',
 10: '100',
 11: '33'}
```

then comes the easy part converting the string values to int and applying `chr` on it to convert back into string.

Since `OP` donot want to use multiple variables or data structures.

```
sample = "Hello World!"
l_n=[str(ord(i))+str(ord('@')) for i in list(sample)]
text="".join(l_n)
n_l=[chr(int(i)) for i in text.split('64') if i.isnumeric()]
''.join(n_l)
```

The problem is we need to know where to apply `char` so I've added an extra `@` to each letter so that it would be easy to convert it back

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: @Ajay Thanks for your answer but I here I have to store d1 dictionary with the data of the number. You can think like I have to convert string to int in one pc and int to string in another pc. I have to store a limited amount of data. Can you suggest me any other way. Thanks

Comment: @YashMakan once `d1` is generated this is not required on other PC

Comment: @Ajay consider line `res1="".join([chr(int(char)) for char in d1.values()])`. You have used d1 to convert int back to string. Therefore I have to store d1 and int in this case...

Answer (score 1):

I am saving the num seperated by " " so it is possible to go back through convert it easier

This works and is simple:

```
i = "Hello World"
num = ""
for char in i:
    num += str(ord(char))+" "

print(''.join(num.split()))

back = ""
for n in num.split():
    back += chr(int(n))

print(back)
```

output:

```
721011081081113287111114108100
Hello World
```